# How to apply a jquery plugin to a div which is generated by knockout template

Tags: jquery, html, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

was wondering if I can apply a jquery plugin to a div which is generated by knockout template.

Here is what I am doing:
I have a template

```
<script type="text/html" id="single-file-image-template">
    <div id="iviewer"></div>
</script>
```

So how can I do something like what I did in jquery style?

```
  var iv = $('#iviewer').iviewer(
      'loadImage', documentUrl
  );
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Regards
Xavier

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom binding as follow :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.iviewer = {
   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
     var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
       //initialize iviewer with url
      $(element).iviewer('loadImage', value);    
    },

     //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).iviewer('loadImage', value);
    }
};
```

And use it this this way :

```
<div data-bind="iviewer : url">
<div>

ko.applyBindings({ url : 'yourUrl'});
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4dUt/)